# Trouble second-order ordinary differential equations with integral terms

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I am a beginner of mma. During the learning of differential equations, I encountered a very difficult problem, a second-order system of ordinary differential equations with integral terms.
    This equation is very complicated to solve by using the built-in function of mma, so I plan to use the self-programmed RK4 method to solve it.After reading the RK4 function written by others, the code I wrote is as follows, but no matter what, I cannot get the result, which makes me very upset.
    I really hope that someone can help me to solve this problem. This is my first question, please forgive me for my unclear wording.

[image]

```
(*RK4*)
rk4[f_, variables_, valtinit_, tinit_, tfinal_, nsteps_] := 
  Module[{table, xlist, ylist, step, k1, k2, k3, k4}, xlist = tinit;
   step = N[(tfinal - tinit)/(nsteps)];
   ylist = valtinit;
   xlist = tinit;
   table = {{xlist, ylist}};
   Table[k1 = 
     step*f /. 
      MapThread[Rule, {variables, ylist}];(*Equivalent to step*
    f/.Thread[Rule[variables,ylist]]*)
    k2 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k1/2 + ylist}];
    k3 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k2/2 + ylist}];
    k4 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k3 + ylist}];
    ylist += 1/6 (k1 + 2 (k2 + k3) + k4);
    xlist += step;
    AppendTo[table, {xlist, ylist}];
    {xlist, ylist}, nsteps];
   table];
```

Here is the code I try

```
(*parameter*)
L = 100;
Cf[z_] := (p1*Sin[(Pi z)/L] + p2*Sin[(2 Pi z)/L])*RealAbs[p1*Sin[(Pi z)/L] + p2*Sin[(2 Pi z)/L]];

funclist = {p1, p2,
   Sin[(Pi t)/L] - q1 - p1 -  NIntegrate[Cf[z]*Sin[(Pi z)/L], {z, 0, L}], 
   Sin[(2 Pi t)/L] - q2 - p2 - NIntegrate[Cf[z]*Sin[(Pi z)/L], {z, 0, L}]};    
initials = {0, 0, 1, 1};
variables = {q1, q2, p1, p2};
init = 0;
final = 10;
nstep = 1000;
approx = rk4[funclist, variables, initials, init, final, nstep]
```

Comment: In the code you have `NIntegrate[Cf[z]*Sin[(Pi z)/L], {z, 0, L}]` and in figure $\int_0^L Cf(z)\sin (\pi x/L)dz$ . Where is it right?

Comment: I‘m sorry, the "-Sin[Pi t/L]" isn't in the intergrate term. And The place where "x" is written in the figure should be "z".The code is right.

Comment: Should there be `Sin[(Pi z)/L]` or `Sin[(2 Pi z)/L]` in the second integral?

Comment: No, they're not in the integral. I've updated the figure of the equation.

Comment: You use RK4 module for an autonomous system. But in your system there is a clear dependence on time through `Sin[(Pi t)/L]` and `Sin[(2 Pi t)/L]`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it makes no sense to use RK4, you can use the standard solver and Gauss quadrature formulas for calculating integrals.

```
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]; L = 100;
np = 60; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}]; Do[
 points[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, L][[i, 1]], {i, 1, np}]
Do[weights[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, L][[i, 2]], {i, 1, 
  np}]
GaussInt[f_, z_] := 
 Sum[(f /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}]

Cf[z_, p1_, p2_] := (p1*Sin[(Pi z)/L] + p2*Sin[(2 Pi z)/L])*
   Abs[p1*Sin[(Pi z)/L] + p2*Sin[(2 Pi z)/L]];
F1[p1_?NumberQ, p2_?NumberQ] := 
  GaussInt[Cf[z, p1, p2]*Sin[(Pi z)/L], z];
F2[p1_?NumberQ, p2_?NumberQ] := 
 GaussInt[Cf[z, p1, p2]*Sin[(2 Pi z)/L], z]
eq = {q1'[t] == p1[t], q2'[t] == p2[t], 
   p1'[t] == Sin[(Pi t)/L] - q1[t] - p1[t] - F1[p1[t], p2[t]], 
   p2'[t] == Sin[(2 Pi t)/L] - q2[t] - p2[t] - F2[p1[t], p2[t]]};
ic = {q1[0] == 0, q2[0] == 0, p1[0] == 1, p2[0] == 1};
var = {q1, q2, p1, p2};


sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic}, var, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"q1", "q2"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]
We will explain how to use `rk4` to solve this problem. Since the system of equations is not autonomous, we include `t` in the number of variables. We remodel `rk4` a bit and compare the result with a standard solver.

```
(*RK4*) rk4[f_, variables_, valtinit_, tinit_, tfinal_, nsteps_] := 
  Module[{table, ylist, step, k1, k2, k3, k4},
   step = N[(tfinal - tinit)/(nsteps)];
   ylist = valtinit;
   
   table = {ylist};
   Table[k1 = 
     step*f /. 
      MapThread[Rule, {variables, ylist}];(*Equivalent to step*
    f/.Thread[Rule[variables,ylist]]*)
    k2 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k1/2 + ylist}];
    k3 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k2/2 + ylist}];
    k4 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k3 + ylist}];
    ylist += 1/6 (k1 + 2 (k2 + k3) + k4);
    
    AppendTo[table, ylist];
    ylist, nsteps];
   table];

(*parameter*)L = 100;
funclist = {p1, p2, Sin[(Pi t)/L] - q1 - p1 - F1[p1, p2], 
   Sin[(2 Pi t)/L] - q2 - p2 - F2[p1, p2], 1};
initials = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
variables = {q1, q2, p1, p2, t};
init = 0;
final = 10;

nstep = 1000;
approx = rk4[funclist, variables, initials, init, final, nstep];
q1s = Table[{approx[[i, 5]], approx[[i, 1]]}, {i, 10, Length[approx], 
    20}];
q2s = Table[{approx[[i, 5]], approx[[i, 2]]}, {i, 10, Length[approx], 
    20}];
Show[Plot[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"q1", "q2"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 ListPlot[{q1s, q2s}]]
```

We see here a rather exact coincidence of numerical solutions.
[image: Figure 2]

We now show how to use `NIntegrate[]` to solve this problem.

```
funclist1 = {p1, p2, Sin[(Pi t)/L] - q1 - p1 - F11[p1, p2], 
   Sin[(2 Pi t)/L] - q2 - p2 - F21[p1, p2], 1};
F11[p1_?NumberQ, p2_?NumberQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Cf[z, p1, p2]*Sin[(Pi z)/L], {z, 0, L}, 
   Method -> {"Trapezoidal", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
F21[p1_?NumberQ, p2_?NumberQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Cf[z, p1, p2]*Sin[(2 Pi z)/L], {z, 0, L}, 
   Method -> {"Trapezoidal", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];

approx = rk4[funclist1, variables, initials, init, final, nstep];

q11s = Table[{approx[[i, 5]], approx[[i, 1]]}, {i, 10, Length[approx],
     20}];
q21s = Table[{approx[[i, 5]], approx[[i, 2]]}, {i, 10, Length[approx],
     20}];
```

We see again here a rather exact coincidence of numerical solutions.

```
Show[Plot[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"q1", "q2"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 ListPlot[{q11s, q21s}]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Compare the three codes for speed: 1) a code using `rk4` and `GaussianQuadratureWeights` - 7.5 seconds; 2) code using `GaussianQuadratureWeights` and `NDSolve` - 1.038 sec; 3) code using `rk4` and `NIntegrate[]` - 9.36 sec. If we remove `?NumberQ` in Definition `F1` and `F2`, as suggested by @xzczd , then the speed increases significantly: 1) - 3.2 s; 2) - 0.23 s.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.If you do the integration well, it's not hard to solve.But I can't think of a way to do that.Finally, thank you very much.

Comment: OK! Do you have an exact solution for comparison?

Comment: Actually it's not necessary to add `?NumberQ`, without it `NDSolve` will be much faster.

Comment: Once we've done the integration, we don't have to do the reduction of the second order differential equation, we can just solve it.I think there is no exact solution to this equation

Comment: @xzczd You're right, I used it by inertia after using `NIntegrate[]`.

Comment: @xzczd why is there a decrease in speed?

Comment: @xzczd so because it already takes `?NumberQ` into account, and specifying it creates a needless call(or calls) to check `True` or `False`?

Comment: @CATrevillian Oops, I misunderstood your previous comment. The code becomes faster without `?NumberQ` in this case because `F1[…]` and `F2[…]` are both calculated symbolically, thus the `Sum[…]` inside `GaussInt[…]` is calculated only once in `F1` and `F2` respectively, while with `?NumericQ` the summation needs to be calculated numerically every time `F1`/`F2` is called.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, Cf(z) is a nonlinear force, and q1 and q2 represent the first two modes of the vibrating system.I might want to solve for modes 5 - 10,That means there are 5-10 coupled equations.And Cf(z) is going to be 5 × 5 terms - 10 × 10 terms.
For j=2
[image]
this processing allows it to be integrated.

[image]
But the result is very unfriendly, and although you can solve it with NDSolve, you can't solve it once the mode increases.The answer is the same as that of Alex Trounev. Thanks for his enthusiasm and answers
[image]

Comment: This is a very interesting solution to the problem. As you can see, all solutions to the problem coincide. I have added an algorithm using `NIntegrate[]` to my answer

Comment: This makes the answer even more perfect

Comment: We can still improve the code, make it faster. I compared the three codes for speed - see update to my answer.